# 500 Internal error in Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatable plugin provided by www.datatables.net.
i am fetching a large no of rows and display on datatable. but the problem is when i am trying to fetch less than or below 5423 records, it's fetching correctly, but it's unable to fetch more than that i.e 5424 is not getting fetched.
I have written code on View:

```js
 var table = $('#GridView').dataTable({
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bSort" : false,
            "bFilter" : false,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "ajax": {
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "POST",
                "url": "/User/BindGridViewUserData2"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "UserId" },
                { "data": "LastName" },
                { "data": "FirstName" },
                { "data": "UserName" },
                { "data": "Password" },
                { "data": "CategoryName" },
                { "data": "HireDate" },
                { "data": "DepartmentName" },
                { "data": "JobTitle" },
                { "data": "FacilityId" },
                { "data": "FacilityName" },
                { "data": "UserStatus" },
                { "data": "RoleId" }
            ]
        });
```

when i run this code, it's showing me 
**500 Internal error**

Can anybody help me

Comment: Hi welkom to Stackoverflow. please read the instructions of how to ask a question and add inline code.

Comment: Include your error message.

Comment: A 500 Server Error is generally the result of an exception in the controller method.

Comment: Have you checked if by some chance the data you request is getting bigger than the maximum allowed content length ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer..
Go to your Controller first then go to the code where you are returning JSON record,
and replace your old code by following code:

```
           var jsonResult = Json(new { aaData = finalList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
           jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
           return jsonResult;
```

It will work 100%..